# What would cause SendInput to stop working after each instance of a key?

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to use SendInput to automate some keystrokes. In simple testing (i.e. opening up notepad and watching the strokes happen), the strokes work fine. Simulating space works over and over, letters, etc.

However, when attempting to send this input to a certain application, SendInput only works for the first instance of a certain key. So, I can send Space once, and the next time I try to send Space it won't actually get sent. (even though it would be sent in any other application) And then I can send A once, but the next time I try to send A it won't send. And so on.

Is this some sort of permission issue I'm running into or something? The initial input works just fine, but following presses of the same key don't.

To provide a bit more substance, here is an example method, assuming all the standard structs:

```
    public static void PressEnter()
    {
        INPUT[] Inputs = new INPUT[1];
        INPUT Input = new INPUT();

        Input.type = 1; // 1 = Keyboard Input
        Input.U.ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.RETURN;
        Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;
        Inputs[0] = Input;

        uint returnInput = SendInput(1, Inputs, INPUT.Size);

        Console.WriteLine(returnInput);
    }
```

I can repeat this over and over with Notepad focused, and returns will continuously be made. However, when sending this over and over to this particular application, only the first goes through. However, I can press Enter on my keyboard and it be accepted just fine. Is it possible for an application to reject input from SendInput?

Comment: To which application are you attempting to send your keystrokes?

Comment: The application is a convoluted record keeping software that I am working on automating (not my place to work on replacing it), and assumed it would be a simple task as I've worked with SendInput in the past, but then I ran into this.

Comment: What happens when you send Space, then A, Then Space.. will it send space for the second time

Comment: Nope, that's one of the things I tried, the keys are still sent the first time but never the second. (or further times)

Comment: Then you need to simulate keyUp event after every keystroke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to simulate a KeyUp flag

```
INPUT input[4];

input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input[0].ki.wVk = 0;
input[0].ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.RETURN;
input[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;

input[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input[1].ki.wVk = 0;
input[1].ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.RETURN;
input[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

input[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input[2].ki.wVk = 0;
input[2].ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.RETURN;
input[2].ki.dwFlags = 0;

input[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input[3].ki.wVk = 0;
input[3].ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.RETURN;
input[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

SendInput(4, input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

> INPUT_KEYBOARD is the input
>
> KEYEVENTF_KEYUP will simulate a KeyUp

In this way you can send multiple keystrokes. Try it, hope this might work for you.

Comment: You are actually right, I never simulated a keyup so I guess the application was stuck in a key down state. After adding a second input to simulate a keyup everything's working perfectly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.